# Get index of pthread without passing it as an argument to a function.

Tags: c, unix, parallel-processing, pthreads

I was told that I can get the index of a pthread in relation to other pthreads (0,1,2, etc.).

However using both

```
pthread_t id = pthread_self();
uint64_t tid;

pthread_threadid_np(NULL, &tid);
```

Gives the following. (for example with 4 pthreads.)

```
2134955
2134954
2134956
2134957

232833024
232296448
233369600
233906176
```

I am looking to get the index of the pthread (0,1,2,3) in this case. Is that possible without sending it as an argument to the pthread function? Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such index.

All you have, portably, is the `pthread_t` returned by `pthread_self()`, which is not even necessarily an integer type, and if it is it certainly doesn't have to be allocated in any particular sequence.

If you want an integer index starting from zero, you need to allocate it yourself.  It doesn't have to be an argument to the thread function, though - you could have a global counter protected by the mutex and each thread can assign itself an ID from that counter and increment it.

Comment: `pthread_t` does not have to be an arithmetic type; pointer is common/reasonable, and in fact it can even be an aggregate type (`struct`).

Comment: @R..: Ahh, I was reading an older version of POSIX, that change was made in Issue 6.